# Laravel 5.5 empty object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Good afternoon guys, I'm having an issue I don't know if you have the same trouble, I upgrade my Laravel project and now all routes like this

```
Route::get('detail/client/{client}', "controller@method")
```

are breaking everything because the object instanced in the controller comes empty...

```
public function detail(FileRequest $request, Client $client){

 dd($client) // empty object
}
```

If someone can help me with this please. If I remove the Client model and make the `dd` then return the ID of the object i.e "594"

Comment: Is that client soft-deleted perhaps?

Comment: Nope I review that, this occurs with every client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't written base Laravel version you are upgrading from, but I think it might have something in common with `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware.

Make sure you have it in middlwareGroups like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class, // <- this is the line you should have
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

in app/Http/Kernel.php file

and also make sure the routes you have problem are in `web` middleware group.

Comment: @LuisJosueUscanga Yes, but you wrote you upgrade your Laravel project so I thought that you are upgrading it from previous version like for example 5.0 or 5.1

Comment: Well I add the binding to my routes but then throws Call to a member function parameters() on null

Comment: Your answer was correct, thanks, I was having problems because I add other middlewares and add the api middleware with the middleware `bindings` to the end of that list of middlewares. I had to put it first of all the middlewares and clean de cache and then it works thank you